# Formatting PHP/Mysql data for jQuery Datatable from Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

Need help to build a table like this https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

I have table with nearly half million rows in mysql. I want to load neary 10k rows in jQuery Datatable through ajax. How can I format like this ?

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
 ...
   [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ]
 ]
}
```

from this

```
foreach ($query as $result){
  ... $result['msgid'], $result['msgdate']...
}
```

What I tried now is

```
$a = '
{
  "data": 
  [';
  foreach($q as $r){ 
    $a.= '[
      "'.$r['msgid'].'",
      "'.$r['msgdate'].'"
    ],';
  }
  $a = rtrim($a,',');
  $a.=']
}';
echo $a;
```

Comment: Show us the server side code. Ar you sure loading 10k rows is a good idea?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, I need to show them all. Directly loading data to `Datatable`, gives php `max timeout` error sometimes. So trying to load data from ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode` function

Comment: This returns `[{"msgid":"366c7869366c313335393838","msgdate":"2016-12-24"}]`

Comment: First you have to create an array which maps your needs then encode it ...

Comment: You can do something like this :json_encode(['data' =>array_values ($q)])

Comment: Or you can use objects as your data source :https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Answer (score 0):

First I would change:

```
$a = '
{
  "data": 
  [';
  foreach($q as $r){ 
    $a.= '[
      "'.$r['msgid'].'",
      "'.$r['msgdate'].'"
    ],';
  }
  $a = rtrim($a,',');
  $a.=']
}';
echo $a;
```

To:

```
echo json_encode(array('data' => $a));
```

Also you can change the `max_execution_time` in the php.ini file.
Consider this way also:

```
    $a = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         array_push($a, $row ); 
    }
```